# Master position not updating on slave-master server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, replication, master-slave

I have 1 master-slave replication and at the same time the slave is master for a MariaDB cluster which will be replacing the actual two DB servers. everything looks fine but the master position on the slave hasn't updated since the cluster was set up the last month.

Slave is doing ok writing from the Master server but the cluster has not been updated ever since.In fact no errors can be observed but noticed the cluster is just the same it was set up since the beginning.

I know that cluster not wirtting new data ha to do with the mater position on the slave.

So the question would be why the master position on the slave is not updating?

**On my MASTER**

mysql> show master status\G;

*************************** 1. row ***************************

File: mysql-bin.000775

Position: 6593494

Binlog_Do_DB:

Binlog_Ignore_DB: mysql,performance_schema,phpmyadmin,information_schema

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

**On my SLAVE:**

MariaDB [(none)]> show slave status\G;

*************************** 1. row ***************************

Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event

Master_Host: master_IP

Master_User: replication

Master_Port: 3306

Connect_Retry: 10

Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000775

Read_Master_Log_Pos: 4192372

Relay_Log_File: slave-relay-bin.002921

Relay_Log_Pos: 2315832

Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000775

Slave_IO_Running: Yes

Slave_SQL_Running: Yes

Also on the SLAVE

MariaDB [(none)]> show master status\G;

*************************** 1. row ***************************

File: mysql-replication.000003

Position: 342

Binlog_Do_DB:

Binlog_Ignore_DB:

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

**On the CLUSTER**

MariaDB [none]> show slave status\G;

*************************** 1. row ***************************

Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event

Master_Host: slave_IP

Master_User: replica

Master_Port: 3306

Connect_Retry: 10

Master_Log_File: mysql-replication.000003

Read_Master_Log_Pos: 342

Relay_Log_File: cluster-relay-bin.000004

Relay_Log_Pos: 645

Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-replication.000003

Slave_IO_Running: Yes

Slave_SQL_Running: Yes

Comment: The cluster slave isn't reading from its master. Have a look at its replication status, specificaly the 'last error' column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A machine will not replicate incoming events to downstream replicas unless you enable `log_slave_updates` on it.

> Normally, a slave does not write any updates that are received from a master server to its own binary log. This option causes the slave to write the updates performed by its SQL thread to its own binary log.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates

(MySQL docs cited, but accurate for MariaDB as well.)

Unrelated, but `Binlog_Ignore_Db` is usually unnecessary and potentially problematic.

Comment: Thx Michael you're correct I had to add log-slave-updates to my.cnf config, restarted instance and start slave again. Now slave-master is replicating to cluster.

Comment: Simply turning that on will not recover the replication items that preceded it.

Comment: @RickJames is of course correct.  You need to rebuild your replica because those events are lost.

Comment: Correct, actually I knew it before asking but wanted to be sure that replication will work fine once a new snapshot was taken. Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

create this table again on both database master and slave then execute following commands on slave server.

1. stop slave
2. set global sql_slave_skip_counter = 1
3. start slave